# Exception The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue in Azure

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

My application is subscribed to an Azure service bus topic. I do some processing when the service receives a message, It works as expected when the processing time is small. But when it takes much time, my services start receiving the same message multiple times.

**Exception Type:** Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException

**Exception Message:** The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue. For more information please see https://aka.ms/ServiceBusExceptions . azure(MessageLockLost)

the value of `MaxAutoRenewDuration` is 2 in this application. So I think if it takes more time it again gets the same message. The `prefetchCount` value is 0 in the application. I have read some articles and understood that If I increase the value of `MaxAutoRenewDuration`, It may solve the problem. But again I would like to know the pros and cons of it.

I have one interesting observation as well, I have added a test subscription on this topic, But this test subscription still shows only one message for this message, But my receiving application is receiving multiple messages, so how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

There are two settings you need to consider in your scenario.

1. `MaxAutoRenewDuration`
2. `LockDuration`

`LockDuration` is defined on the entity you receive from. It should alsway be **less** than `MaxAutoRenewDuration`. So if processing takes up to 5 minutes but can spike to 7, you should set `LockDuration` to the max 5 minutes and `MaxAutoRenewDuration` to something greater than 7.

Comment: You mean the LockDuratiom is set in the sender application who sends message to the topic?

Comment: So as per the example in your answer, if message processing is taking more then 5 mins, will it renew lock for 7 more minutes or 2 (7-5) more minutes?

Comment: If you set `MaxAutoRenewDuration`, you'll get additional 2 minutes. But you shouldn't be specifying a value that's right on the edge. Rather, set something to have enough buffer. Like 10 mins. The lock will be released when the message is completed. But if there's an exception, the lock will be held for some time the Processor is managing. IIRC, the Processor is not locking the whole time upfront.

Comment: How and where to set LockDuration?

Comment: I’m not setting LockDuration anywhere in my code and I’m setting MaxAutoRenewDuration value as 2, so does it make any sense? Does it have any impact at all or not? Because AFAIK Iif I don’t set LockDuration, its default value will be 5. And MaxAutoRenewDuration should be greater than it

Comment: `LockDuration` is not set in the code. It's set on the entity (queue or subscription).

Answer (score 0):

For Service Bus, each message is locked by the service when a consumer reads and that consumer has exclusive access to the message until either they settle the message (complete, abandon, dead-letter, etc) or until the lock is held long enough that it expires.

To allow for processing that may go on longer than the lock duration but that also may be variable enough that you don't want to increase the duration for all consumers, the `ServiceBusProcessor` will automatically renew the lock for messages that have been read while the processing handler is still active for those messages.

The `MaxAutoRenewDuration` option controls how long the processor will renew the message lock for you while your processing takes place.  The general recommendation for this value is "long enough that it covers the longest time processing should take", with the intent being to ensure that any delays when processing the message such as retries or slow downstream systems don't cause failures.

The trade-off that you're making is how long this consumer will continue to have exclusive access in the case where your processing hangs or behaves unexpectedly.  A shorter `MaxAutoRenewDuration` will allow the lock to expire and another consumer (possibly the same instance) to read the message again so that processing is not delayed.  That comes with the cost that if processing runs longer than this time, the lock may be lost before it is finished and you may process that message again.

In your scenario, it sounds like your processing can sometimes take longer than that duration and the lock is expiring, and it would be helpful to increase unless your application is sensitive to latency and would prefer to process multiple times to reduce delays.

> I have one interesting observation as well, I have added a test subscription on this topic, But this test subscription still shows only one message for this message, But my receiving application is receiving multiple messages, so how does it work?

There's not enough context to answer that authoritatively.  How you're determining that the "subscription shows only one message"?  What does "receiving multiple messages" mean - that you're doing batch receives, that you're seeing this message replay, or that you're seeing multiple messages dispatched for processing?

Comment: I still didn’t get my answer, what shall I do in this situation to solve this problem?

Comment: I am using ServiceBusExplorer, my receiver service is subscribed to a topic with one subscription, I have added one more subscription to check how many messages I’m getting on the topic. My subscription shows only one message, but my receiver handler gets multiple messages in this scenario. I hope it’s clear now

Comment: Last paragraph before the quote: "In your scenario, it sounds like your processing can sometimes take longer than that duration and the lock is expiring, and it would be helpful to increase unless your application is sensitive to latency and would prefer to process multiple times to reduce delays."

Comment: When you say "multiple messages" are these unique data or duplicated?

Comment: duplicated data

Comment: That indicates the message is not being explicitly settled - either the lock is expired or there was an exception leaked during processing.  This is expected behavior.  The message will continue to be redelivered until either it is settled or the configured delivery count is exceeded, at which point the service will dead-letter it.  More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#maximum-delivery-count

Comment: Do you have idea where and how to set LockDuration in my scenario?

Comment: In the Azure portal or via one of the Azure CLIs; it's a setting on the resource itself, not something controlled by the client.